# Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ left fixed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

In this example I get that 1 is left fixed, because every multiplicative element of an isomorphism is left fixed?, but why is $\mathbb{Q}$ left fixed as a consequence of this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is generated as a field by $1$. Thus if $1$ is mapped to itself, then so is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you lease elaborate? Do you mean that 1 generates $\mathbb{Q}$ if we view it as a vector space, and then 1 times the elements of $mathbb{Q}$ is all the rational numbers? And how do you use this with an isomorphism?

Comment: Not as a vector space, as a field. You can use addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division to create every rational using only the element 1. These operations are preserved by homomorphism.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The fixed field is a field and the smallest subfield containing $1$ is $\mathbb Q$ because $\mathbb Q$ has no proper subfields.

More directly: Any field automoprhism $\phi$ fixes $1$ and $0$. If $\phi(n)=n$, then also $\phi(n+1)=\phi(n)+\phi(1)=n+1$. Hence $\phi$ fixes $\mathbb N$. If $\phi(x)=x$ then $0=\phi(0)=\phi(x-x)=\phi(x)+\phi(-x)$ implies $\phi(-x)=-\phi(x)=-x$. Hence $\phi$ fixes $\mathbb Z$.
If $\phi$ fixes $nx$ with $n\in\mathbb N$, then $nx = \phi(nx)=\phi(x+x+\ldots+x)=\phi(x)+\phi(x)+\ldots+\phi(x)=n\phi(x)$ and hence $\phi(x)=x$. Hence $\phi$ fixes $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now, but do you also need this? :$\phi(z_1/z_2)=\phi(z_1z_2^{-1})=\phi(z_1)\phi(z_2^{-1})=\phi(z_1)\phi(z_2)^{-1}=\phi(z_1)/\phi(z_2)=z_1/z_2$?